# HangMan Comand Within Command

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So what I am trying to do here is when the command is used, the new channel is created, then the user mentions the channel and puts their word, then the hangman is sent within the channel they mentioned. But I get lost cause rn it's running everything at once, how do I make it listen for a new "command"?

```js
const { hangman } = require('reconlx')

module.exports = {
    name : 'hangman',
    description: "Wanna play hangman?",
    aliases: ['hang'],
    execute(client, message, args, Discord) {
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send('You need manage messages permission.')
        const channel = message.mentions.channels.first() || message.guild.channels.cache.get(args[0])
        message.guild.channels.create(`HangMan`, {
            type: 'text',
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: message.guild.id,
                    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
                },
                {
                    id: message.author.id,
                    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'ADD_REACTIONS', 'ATTACH_FILES']
                }
            ]
        }).then(async channel => {
            channel.send("Please mention a channel, then add your word. It should look something like this `#the game channel (your word)`")
            message.reply(`Scroll to the very top of the server to add your word! <#${channel.id}>`)
        })

        if(message.content.includes('#')) {
            message.reply('Hangman has started!')};

            
        if(!channel) return message.channel.send('Please specify a channel')
        const word = args.slice(1).join(" ")
        if(!word) return  message.channel.send('Please specify a word to guess.')

        const hang = new hangman({
            message: message,
            word: word,
            client: client,
            channelID: channel.id,
        })

        hang.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using [TextChannel#awaitMessages()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages)

Comment: ok thank you, couldn't find it and I'm kinda new so learning as a go